# Can we display a self-created character on our web page?

Tags: web, unicode, character, typography

This character doesn't exist in Unicode since I created it myself. Now, it is in an esp file format. After some searches, and my understanding, I can't just put it into Unicode.

My goal is to display it, let my viewers to see if they like it, but not in any picture format since it also serves other purposes for the website, where displaying it as an image is just not considered.

How can we display a self-created character where it could ONLY be displayed as a regular letter?

Comment: you can't.  Your system has no clue what that letter is.

Comment: Even on the web , can we have some kind of library of characters to displays?

Comment: Create a custom font for rendering the character, and then [embed that font on your website](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, The character I plan to display is not exited yet, so it is not really a font issue. 
Of you mean we just replace a character with our desired look, then display it ?

Comment: I said what I mean. Create a custom font (you can't use an EPS file as a font). Choose an unused Unicode character (there are private-use characters available) and make the font render that character however you want. Then embed that font in your website, and use that Unicode character in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, but we should be really careful doing so.

As Remy Lebau suggested, if you really insist on using custom glyph as "regular letter" inside text flow, you should

- create a real font file to be placed on web (WOFF/OTF), or installed on each user device (OTF/TTF),
- ensure that custom glyph in your font file is assigned to some code point from the ["private-use" area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas),
- use the code point in `unicode-range` value of `@font-face`,
- and add newly created `font-family` to the font stack.

Example:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: f;
 src: local(Impact), local(Haettenschweiler), local(Helvetica Inserat);
 unicode-range: U+65;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: f;
 src: local(Courier new), local(Menlo), local(Liberation Mono);
 unicode-range: U+6f;
}
body { font-family: f, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<p>Some text where letters "o" and "e" are from a different ("custom") font-faces.</p>
```

Font-face with only private-use characters should work even as a last (fallback) in the stack, but it does not matter here.  In your case those "`local()`" declarations would be replaced with `url()` path or dataURI. If your target audience is in controlled environment (intranet) and you can reliably distribute the to all consuming devices, you can use even the `local([name of locally installed ustom font])`

The `unicode-range` value would be something like `U+F8FF`.

But, use this in and only if you are sure your users will

### Why you probably should not do that this way

If there is chance (some of) your users have not installed, does not support, can not download or are blocking given font, **or is using assistive technology** to consume your content and given glyph conveys some meaningful information, you probably should refrain from using the approach described above.

If you don't have such controlled audience and want to support screen readers, and still don't want to use simple `<img alt="[glyph meaning in the context]">`, you should at least wrap their occurrences as suggested in [Léonie Watson's article Accessible emoji](https://tink.uk/accessible-emoji/):

```html
Some text <span role="img" aria-label="[glyph meaning in the context]">&#xf8ff;</span>
```